# GetAddrInfo example from Wikipedia won't work

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, operating-system

I've been learning how to use getaddrinfo() recently. I referred to Wikipedia for an example:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo
I made some small modifications to the example code to compile it with Visual C++ 2005.
The modified version is as follows:

```
int main(){

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

struct addrinfo *res;
int error;

/* resolve the domain name into a list of addresses */
error = getaddrinfo("www.example.com", NULL, NULL, &result);
if (error != 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", error); 
    fprintf(stderr, "error in getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(error));

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}   

/* loop over all returned results and do inverse lookup */
for (res = result; res != NULL; res = res->ai_next)
{   
    char hostname[NI_MAXHOST] = "";

    error = getnameinfo(res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen, hostname, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, 0); 
    if (error != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        fprintf(stderr, "error in getnameinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(error));
        continue;
    }
    if (*hostname != '\0')
        printf("hostname: %s\n", hostname);
}   

freeaddrinfo(result);

getchar();

return 0;
}
```

The execution result is surprisingly failed with a return error:`WSANO_DATA`.
Nevertheless, I can connect to `www.example.com` with Google Chrome.
I've also replaced `www.example.com` with other domain names in the code and done tests. Some of the results are expected while some others are strange:

> test: localhost
>   hostname: localhost
>   
>   test: www.yahoo.com.tw
>   hostname: w2.rc.vip.gq1.yahoo.com
>   hostname: w2.rc.vip.sp1.yahoo.com

The first result is as expected, but the second(www.yahoo.com.tw) is strange. I can't connect to "w2.rc.vip.gq1.yahoo.com" and "w2.rc.vip.sp1.yahoo.com" via the browser.

**Could anyone explain why I got the above results and why the original example from Wikipedia didn't work? Thanks a lot.**

Comment: The two result you get for Yahoo might be two load-balancing servers, or something else, and they might not allow anything except `www.yahoo.com.tw` to connect.

Comment: Where does this `WSANO_DATA` occur?

Comment: To @glglgl : `WSANO_DATA` occurs just after I tried to call `getnameinfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

The example and your code work just fine.

Connecting directly to the address of Yahoo's load balancer should not work as it's meant to forward your request to a front end delivery server based on the domain, subdomain and route.

You can find more info on wiki about [Load balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29) and how it works.

As for the error, try flushing your DNS cache before retesting. It can be done with `ipconfig /flushdns` on Windows.

Comment: I've tried `ipconfig /flushdns` but the code still didn't work with `www.example.com`.  
Nevertheless, I used `nslookup` in the `cmd` shell to resolve `www.example.com` and get the IP address, `93.184.216.119`, which is replied from Google DNS, `8.8.8.8`. Then I passed the resulting IP to `nslookup` and got the failed message:

_"*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find 92.184.216.119: Non-existent domain._"
Did that mean it's the problem of Google DNS that couldn't resolve the hostname of `www.example.com`?